# How do you get row numbers to show in a <h:dataTable>?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have the following JSF datatable:

```
<h:dataTable border="1" var="f2" value="#{someEJB.list}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">No</f:facet>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>#{f2.name}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

How can I show the row numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`UIData#getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex%28%29) for this.

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{table}" ...>
    <h:column>
        #{table.rowIndex + 1}
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```